# How many times do I pay rent?

Tags: united-kingdom, rent

First question here, apologies for any mistakes

I have just finished renting my first place and have now moved to a new flat

The Landlord of the previous place has taken a months rent for the previous place, by debit card. The previous contract was from 04/09/2018 to 04/09/2019 (12 months)

Some details (verbatim from contract):

> Term - For the 12 months commencing 4th September 2018
>
> Rent - x Per a Month
>
> Payment - In advance by equal payments on the 4th of every month

To me that means I pay rent from September 2018 to August 2019 (12 months)

Am I wrong in my reading of this?

---

Additional information:

I started renting the place from September 2017 and paid the deposit and first months rent in september of that year. And renewed the contract for September 2018 to 2019

In my opinion, the landlord doesnt seem to like me (unsure why, we hardly spoke to each other and it was short & to the point)

Comment: Unrelated to your question per se, but regarding your last point, what's "short and to the point" to some is at least "brusque" to others. That said, I would expect someone who offers even just a single apartment for rent would be able to deal with a little "brusque"; certainly as long as it doesn't cross over into "rude".

Comment: @aCVn Updated the tags to include UK. Regarding your second comment, quite possible but we only spoke to each other 1 - 2 times a year. Its mostly fluff should it be neccessary

Comment: Your landlord's opinion of you doesn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: Shouldn't your *own* records indicate how much money left your possession?

Comment: @chepner I know how much money has left my account, its how many times it should have been taken.

Comment: OK, so that's something initiated by the landlord (perhaps via an automatic arrangement). Have you asked the landlord about the money?

Comment: @Mr.Burns After a year, does it matter? It was almost certainly taken out monthly, though at this point it could have been taken as a single lump sum and it doesn't change your current account status. (As an aside, I encourage you to pay more attention to your finances, as you should have *some* sort of statement that clearly shows each withdrawal.)

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I have spoken to them, and after a bit of 'poking' it turns out the payment was made in error

Comment: Maybe it's just me as an air-headed American, but I was really scratching my head over the dates in your question (04/09/2018 interpreted as April 8th when you meant August 4th). Maybe a quick edit to spell them out instead of using DD/MM/YYYY (as opposed to the American MM/DD/YYYY) would prevent others from being confused as well.

Comment: @dwizum I was confused to, but your edit would confuse others.  Better to use ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD and everyone will understand.

Comment: @RonJohn maybe it wasn't clear, but my suggestion was to literally spell them out as written words, i.e. "August 4th" instead of a number based format, not sure how that would be confusing to anyone?

Comment: Did you inform the landlord that you were planning to move out? Your contract should say if you have to give notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You paid rent 12 times, in compliance with "Payment - In advance by equal payments on the 4th of every month"

1. 2018-09-04, for the period 2018-09-04/2018-10-03
2. 2018-10-04, for the period 2018-10-04/2018-11-03
3. 2018-11-04, etc.
4. 2018-12-04
5. 2019-01-04
6. 2019-02-04
7. 2019-03-04
8. 2019-04-04
9. 2019-05-04
10. 2019-06-04
11. 2019-07-04
12. 2019-08-04

Since you were extending a previous contract, it seems clear that your rent was paid automatically, as it had been for the preceding months, on the day the final 12-month lease began. No rent should have been deducted on 2019-09-04, as that would be for the period 2019-09-04/2019-10-03, and your lease does not cover that.